# NextAuth exposing next-auth.session-token to token.user object

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js13, next-auth

After trying multiple ways and going through numerous articles and videos, I am still not able to solve a trivial issue. I have used nextAuth in my fullstack next app. I am using NextAuth v4 and nextJS v14. I tried to implement a the credential provider for my app, while the whole authentication works smoothly, I want to be able to set the accessToken in my returned session object so that I can use it to make API calls from my frontend to my server due to the token auth mechanism I have set for my APIs. Right now, I manually copy paste the token from my browser cookies and then make calls to my APIs. This works, but I want to be able to extract it from the useSession() on client side and use it to make API calls.

**This is my api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts:**

```
import { AuthOptions } from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import { connectToDatabase } from './mongodb/mongodb';
import { IUser, UserModel } from '@/models/user.model';

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {},

      //@ts-ignore
      async authorize(credentials: { email: string; password: string }) {
        try {
          await connectToDatabase();
          const user = await UserModel.findOne({
            email: credentials.email,
          });

          if (user) {
            const isPasswordCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(
              credentials.password,
              user.password,
            );

            if (isPasswordCorrect) {
              let currentUser = {
                id: user.id,
                name: user.name,
                email: user.email,
                role: user.role,
                isSuperAdmin: user.isSuperAdmin,
              };

              return Promise.resolve(currentUser);
            }
          }
          return Promise.resolve(null);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error during authentication:', error);
          // Return null in case of an error
          return Promise.resolve(null);
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    session({ session, token, user }) {
      if (token.user !== undefined) {
        session.user = token.user as IUser;
      }
      return session;
    },
    async redirect({ baseUrl }) {
      return baseUrl + '/dashboard';
    },
    //@ts-ignore
    jwt({ token, user, account }) {
      console.log(token);

      if (account?.provider === 'credentials' && user !== undefined) {
        token.user = user;
      }
      return token;
    },
  },
  jwt: {
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login',
  },
};
```

**
This is my next-auth.d.ts file:
**

```
// next-auth.d.ts
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import { IUser } from '@/models/user.model'; // Adjust the path accordingly

declare module 'next-auth' {
  interface Session {
    user: IUser; // Add your custom user model
    token: {
      role: 'chef' | 'waiter'; // Add properties from your token
    };
  }
}
```

I am using mongoDB, mongoose.

I can see my session-token in cookies upon successful login:
[image]

currently I see this for my session on client side, I want to be able to see a field for accessToken in my response below which allows me to extract this value and use it to make API calls from client side:

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": "jgdgd78789dhdujhkd",
        "name": "Sam Rodrigaz",
        "email": "sam@gmail.com",
        "role": "chef",
        "isSuperAdmin": false
    },
    "expires": "2024-03-08T04:11:30.477Z"
}
```

I want the returned session user object to be:

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": "jgdgd78789dhdujhkd",
        "name": "Sam Rodrigaz",
        "email": "sam@gmail.com",
        "role": "chef",
        "isSuperAdmin": false,
        "accessToken": "eyh79bjbk....." (basically the session token from my cookies)
    },
    "expires": "2024-03-08T04:11:30.477Z"
}
```